# Is it necessary to rename .js files to invalidate cache?

Tags: javascript, frontend, gulp, browser-cache

I want to invalidate cached app.js after every single release.

**Short question**:

Is it necessary to physically rename(by [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), for example) `app.js` to `app-a23ds.js` every time or is enough to add param with hash in html like `app.js?_=<build number>`

**Description**:

I was sure before that is enought to write something like `app.js?_=<build number>` in  index.html to load new file instead of cahed. But when I'm investigate this question deeper I found a few of huge solutions for this case. Like [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev). The main idea of them is to write a new file with new filename (old filename + revisions hash). Is it really neccessary or what?

Comment: IMHO it is best practice to to rename the file every release.

Comment: Thank for imho, but I'm still wonder is `app.js?_=<build number>` would work? Or it wouldn't at all?

Comment: The cache will *only* work on files with the *exact* same resource URI. Changing the URI in any way, including the query fragment, makes it a *different* resource.

Comment: In my experience changing the query string does not always work, but changing the file name **always** works.

Comment: @Petah, It's quite interesting. In what cases query string doesn't work. Can you provide some examples, please?

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov for example if you configured a proxy to ignore them: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent